# I'm getting this issue when trying to run the code I found on GitHub. Pydot and graphivz are installed but still getting this error

Tags: matplotlib, keras, pydot

```
    2022-07-19 18:41:58.081967: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:41:58.082145: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-07-19 18:42:01.316963: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.317546: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.318073: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.318783: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.319328: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.319857: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.320492: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.321261: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2022-07-19 18:42:01.321404: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2022-07-19 18:42:01.321943: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
 --------- Training --------- 
Weight for class fire : 0.84
Weight for class No_fire : 1.24
Found 8617 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 6894 files for training.
Found 8617 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 1723 files for validation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hobiler\PythonDers\Programlar\SaDe\main.py", line 80, in <module>
    train_keras()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hobiler\PythonDers\Programlar\SaDe\training.py", line 114, in train_keras
    keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 421, in plot_model
    dot = model_to_dot(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 163, in model_to_dot
    raise ImportError(message)
ImportError: You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried using

```
pip install pydot
pip install pydotplus
pip install graphviz
```

commands. But still got this error.I'm new to machine learning and I would appreciate it if you could help me a bit.

[Here](https://github.com/AlirezaShamsoshoara/Fire-Detection-UAV-Aerial-Image-Classification-Segmentation-UnmannedAerialVehicle) is the GitHub of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are two software systems named Graphviz.  You need both.
Go here https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/ and download the appropriate version (pip won't solve your problem)