# Azure ML ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tags: python, graphviz, azure-machine-learning-service, lightgbm

I am using LightGBM in Azure ML Jupyter notebooks, it works fine and I also installed graphviz.

However this line:

```
lgb.plot_tree(clf, tree_index = 1, figsize=(20,12))
```

throws this error:

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common problem (very common).  There are two systems named Graphviz, and you need both!
see [I'm getting this issue when trying to run the code I found on GitHub. Pydot and graphivz are installed but still getting this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73040021/im-getting-this-issue-when-trying-to-run-the-code-i-found-on-github-pydot-and/73041302#73041302)